# Error: Language string failed to load: instantiate

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, message

I am working on sending some emails and PHPMailer have been working perfectly on my test server.

Now, after i moved it to the production server, none of my mails will fire and i am getting a

Mailer Error: Language string failed to load: instantiate.

I have been googling and toiling with phpmailer to see what seems to be the problem and from what i gathered, i was not able to make a regular php mail() request (this is the var that needs to return true for the error to stop.

I am working on sending some emails and PHPMailer have been working perfectly on my test server.

```php
try {
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username   = $mail_user_name;                        // SMTP username
            $mail->Password   = $mail_user_password;                    // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

            //Recipients

            $mail->setFrom($customerservice_email, $customerservice_name);
            $mail->addAddress('email@gmail.com'); // reciever email address
            // $mail->addAddress('info@akhil.com');     // Add a recipient
            // $mail->addAddress($to);
            $mail->SetLanguage('en');
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->MsgHTML($message);

            if($mail->send()){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            print_r($e);die;
            return false;
        }
```

Anyone have anything to help me out with? It is getting extremly frustration at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). Literally the first thing it tells you is to *make sure you're running the latest version,* which you're not doing. That "language string" error message was removed from PHPMailer many years ago. Upgrade and the problem will go away.

You may well still have a problem after that, but whatever it is, it will probably be covered in the same troubleshooting guide.